# Vuejs: endless loop when assigning a value to a variable

Tags: infinite-loop, vuejs2

I am working on a timeline that allows the user to take notes on a customer.
I would like to display the month and the year before the group of notes that belongs to that month.

For example :

```
February 2016
"Note 4" - 2016-02-15
"Note 3" - 2016-02-05

January 2016
"Note 2" - 2016-01-28
"Note 1" - 2016-01-12
```

As I use VueJS to display my notes, I wanted to test each note to check if the month was different from the month saved in a variable called "currentMonth".
So I used a v-if in my display to check the value with a function called "isNewMonth" :

```
<div v-for="note in notes | orderBy 'date' -1" >
    <div v-if="isNewMonth(note)"><% currentMonth %></div>
    <div style="background-color: #<% note.type.color %>; margin-bottom: 10px; border-left: solid #<% note.type.border_color %> 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
      <p class="noteMessage"><% note.message %><p>
      <p class="noteInfos">Par <% note.author %> le <% note.date %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the function isNewMonth :

```
isNewMonth: function(note) {
  var noteMonth = parseInt(note.date.split("-")[1]);
  if(this.currentMonth != noteMonth)
  {
    this.$set('currentMonth', noteMonth);
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have an issue with the line "this.$set('currentMonth', noteMonth);". When I add this line, I am stuck in an endless loop.
Whenever I remove this line everything is fine (but it always display the month before each note).

Do you know a way to solve my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about infinite loop, but you can not do this with the current approach.

`currentMonth` is a single variable and vueJs have two way data binding, what I am saying is, if you change `currentMonth` once, it will be changed at all the places. It is not that for first loop it will show one value and for next loop it will set other value.

It will always show the latest value.

Instead you can do something like following:

```
<div v-for="(note, index) in notes | orderBy 'date' -1" >
    <div v-if="hasMonthchanged(note, index)"><% getMonth(note) %></div>
    <div style="background-color: #<% note.type.color %>; margin-bottom: 10px; border-left: solid #<% note.type.border_color %> 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
      <p class="noteMessage"><% note.message %><p>
      <p class="noteInfos">Par <% note.author %> le <% note.date %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

where `hasMonthchanged` is the function which will return whether monthe has been changed

You can just compare with last note, whether month has changed or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I did not think about the issue with currentMonth, I was probably distracted when I did this ^^
It works perfectly =)